# Reachbility in ios does not give callback when wifi access point switches

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, reachability

I am new to ios. I am developing a voip application. In my application I need callback when device ip address changes. I have added [Reachability code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) in my application. But when go in wifi settings in iphone and cconnect to wifi router other than the currently connected router.
It gives reachability callback. But sometimes it does not give this callback. Why does this happen? Is code of Reachability is buggy?
Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show some code related to Reachability to us?

Comment: Yes. I have used sample code of [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) given by apple.

Comment: @Mdroid any progress with this?